# Using JWT along with refresh tokens in Spring OAuth2

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

Consider we want to use `JWT` along with refresh tokens in Spring.
We have to use `JWTTokenStore`, right?

But if `JWTTokenStore` isn't a real database and doesn't store anything, where and how should we store refresh tokens?

(We prefer to store refresh tokens in database rather than store them in memory)

Answer (score 1):

Refresh tokens are JWTs by default if the access tokens are. To change that you would have to modify the token services (possibly a custom `TokenEnhancer` would do it, and maybe also a custom `TokenStore`). Why not go with the default?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The explanation for me is that the tokens was set in the cookies.(No sessions on client side). And I don't want that my refresh token be used like an access token. (Modifying the access token cookie with the value of the refresh token)